# Создание встроенной базы данных в NetBeans

Tags: sql

Могу ли я в имеющийся Java проект встроить базу данных MySQL. Не localhost, а так, чтобы файл базы был в корневой папке проекта?

Comment: Вам нужна встроенная БД - embedded database. Выбирайте подходящую: [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database), [2](http://embedded-databases.com/).

Answer (score 0):

По-моему [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34880061/how-to-connect-sqlite-database-to-netbeans) как раз решение такой задачи. SQLite как раз работает только с файлами.

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать при помощи [MySQL Embedded](https://www.mysql.com/oem/).

В дистрибутив MySQL входит специальная библиотека, которая обеспечивает соответствующий функционал. Есть библиотеки для работы с MySQL Embedded и для Java (например, [mysql-je](http://mysql-je.sourceforge.net/)).

P.S. Если честно, для таких задач лучше всё-таки использовать SQLite или Derby.